# How To Improve Multiple JOIN Performance For SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, join, cassandra

Suppose I have a Spotify-Liked app and has schema as below:

[image]

After user login, and click on My Songs button, a query needs to be returned all purchased song for this user.

According to the above schema, I need to write a SQL like:

```
select s.name, al.name, ar.name, g.genres
from users u 
join purchases p on u.id = p.userid
join purchaseitem pi on p.id= pi.purchaseid
join songs s on pi.itemid = s.id
join albums al on al.id = s.albumid
join genres g on g.id = s.genreid
join artists ar on ar.id = al.artisted
```

This ugly and multiple joins query may be causing significant performance issues.

1. What enhancement we can do to the query itself?
2. If nothing we can do on the SQL query, how the database schema can be redesign to enhance this capability?
3. If we are able to partition SQL database, i.e, indexing, will it help improve performance?
4. If performance is the only concern, will a NoSQL database such as Cassandra or MongoDB be a better choice?

Comment: Ugly? Try normal :) that looks perfectly correct for a well normalised database. Thats exactly why they are called a relational database.

Comment: As for performance, what performance issues are you experiencing? And please provide an execution plan if you are looking for assistance.

Comment: We cannot advise on whether a no-sql database is a better choice without understanding your complete application system.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your foreign keys? I agree with Dale, that schema looks pretty darn nice to me. Way better than most. One clarification - when Dale said "that's why their called relational", he didn't mean "because they contain relationships between different tables". The "relational" part means that within a single table are all the elements that are "related to" (functionally dependent upon) a key. Together, those columns form what is known as a "relation". Hence "relational database". In SQL, "table" is roughly equivalent to "relation" (or really "relation variable").

Comment: "may be causing" ?

Comment: @allmhuran actually I did in fact mean that :) because many of the definitions for a relational database do in fact define it by the fact that tables can have relationships. However I see from looking at the theoretical definition that you are in fact correct. Interesting.

Comment: @DaleK Haha, I thought I'd give you the benefit of the doubt because you clearly know your stuff :)

Comment: FWIW - Spotify was one of the earliest users of Apache Cassandra, and has also contributed to its code base.  But just simply using Cassandra instead of a RDBMS won't improve things in and of itself.  The entire model would have to be rebuilt, "denormalized," and engineered for the specific queries that it would be expected to serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can denormalize purchase item table and keep all other data (album name, artist name, etc) in purchaseitem table. Once the purchase is done then data will not change.

E.g What if you change artist name after purchase. Then later your reports will have a new artist name but not the name of the artist exists in the time of purchase.

Dont you need to keep purchase history in the system. ?

Then you can simplify this quarry but y**ou have to think about your overall design** this may be a one quarry in your solution. When your redundancing the data, you have to make sure that you have correct controls in the system.  There is no hard and fast rule to normalize all data in a relational database.

You can improve read performance by denormalizing tables but it impacts the insert and updates.  You need to balance these with your requirement

Going for NOSQL will not be a silver bullet. You can handle millions of records in a relational database system with a proper design. Also, the microservices pattern can be used for scalability but it will complex your design and technology stack.